# What primes can ramify and decompose in $k(\mu_{p^m}) \mid k$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, cyclic-groups, roots-of-unity

Let $k$ be a number field and $p$ be a rational prime. Then consider the extension $k(\mu_{p^m}) \mid k$ of adjoining all roots of unity of degree $p^m$ to $k$.  Assuming that $\mu_{p^m} \cap k$ is non-trivial:

How to find the Galois group of this extension?
Also which primes of $k$ can ramify/decompose in this extension? I don't know how to tackle this problem properly, but it should not be that difficult.

I know so far that the extension $k(\mu_{p^m}) \mid k$ is of degree less than $\varphi(p^m) = p^{m-1}(p-1)$, where $\varphi$ denotes the Eulerian Phi-function.

Is the Galois group now isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} / (p^{m-1}(p-1)) \mathbb{Z}$, since the extension by roots of unity must be cyclic?

Thanks, 
Tom

Comment: Actually, even if $\mu_{p^m}\cap k$ is trivial (so $\pm1$ if $p=2$ and $\varnothing$ otherwise), the degree can still be less than $\varphi(p^m)$. For example, if $k=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ then $k(\mu_5)/k$ has degree $2$. In any case the Galois group will be a subgroup of $(\Bbb Z/p^m\Bbb Z)^\times$ which depends I think on $k$'s roots of unity, and the invariant which describes which primes ramify is the *relative discriminant* (those that ramify are precisely the ones dividing $\Delta_{L/K}$).

Comment: @seaturtles Thank you, and I'm aware of the relative discriminant. But are there further statements for my special case of relative extension? Maybe in the case $m=1$?